# Email de confirmacao de registro do form com codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Eai pessoal. Tenho o seguinte cenário...

Queria enviar um email pro usuário do meu site. 
Por exemplo: - Seja bem vindo a empresa Fulano, aguarde que logo entraremos em contato.

Este é só um exemplo, mas no meu form real tenho outros campos(tipo: nome, email, endereco, cidade, estado, plano escolhido e outros).

Então, o objetivo seria que quando ele preenchesse o formulario por completo, fosse enviado pro email que ele forneceu no momento do registro, a mensagem que eu disse mais em cima. (Seja bem vindo.....)

obs:

- controller Contato: tenho duas funcoes, enviaEmail(); e checkEmail()
- enviaEmail(): ele funciona, os dados do formulario chega no email do meu servidor.
- o erro está no checkEmail() nessa linha $address = $this->enviaEmail($email);

O erro diz que a variavel $email nao foi definida.

Se alguém tiver outra ideia de realizar o mesmo processo, toda ajuda é bem vinda!

```
<?php
```

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Contato extends CI_Controller {

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}

public function index(){
    $this->load->view('contato');    
}

// funcao: envia o email informando para o usuario que o registro foi recebido
public function checkEmail(){

// config do servidor de email
    $config = array();
    $config ['charset'] = 'utf8';
    $config ['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config ['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config ['smtp_host'] = '';
    $config ['smtp_user'] = 'lucas.teste@email.com.br';
    $config ['smtp_pass'] = '';
    $config ['smtp_port'] = 25;

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $address = $this->enviaEmail($email);

// formatacao do corpo de email
    $this->email->from('lucas.teste@email.com.br');
    $this->email->to($address);
    $this->email->subject('Confirmação de recebimento!');       
    $this->email->message('
        <html>
        <head>

        <style>
          .card {
        border: 1px solid #ededed;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 43px 40px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #FFA100;
          }

          .page-footer{padding: 43px 40px;}

          body{background-color:#D9EBFF;}

          h2 {color: #002040; font-size: 16px;}

        </style>
        </head>
        <body>

         <div class="">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Olá, seja Bem Vindo! Nome Empresa agradecece pela sua escolha!</h2><br>

      <p>O seu email foi recebido pelo nosso atendimento, aguarde que entraremos em contato para mais informações</p>

    </div>
     </div>


     <div class="page-footer">
        <p>Sua Empresa | Todos os direitos reservados</p>
     </div>

        </body>
        </html>

    '); 

    if ($this->email->send()){
        echo "email enviado";
    }
    else{
        echo "erro ao enviar";

    }
}

//funcao que envia o email pro usuario que fez o registro no formulario
public function enviaEmail(){

   //validacao do formulario
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome','nome', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[30]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mensagem','mensagem', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[144]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('item','item', 'required');

    $data = $this->input->post();

// config servidor de email
    $config = array();
    $config ['charset'] = 'utf8';
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config ['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config ['smtp_host'] = '';
    $config ['smtp_user'] = 'lucas.teste@email.com.br';
    $config ['smtp_pass'] = '';
    $config ['smtp_port'] = 25;

    // recebe os valores dos campos preenchidos pelo usuario
    $nome = $this->input->post('nome', TRUE);
    $email = $this->input->post('email', TRUE);
    $emailTo = $this->input->post('email', TRUE);
    $item = $this->input->post('item', TRUE);
    $mensagem = $this->input->post('mensagem', TRUE);


    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// formatacao do corpo de email
    $this->email->from($data['email']);
    $this->email->to('lucas.teste@email.com.br');
    $this->email->subject('Entre em Contato');      
    $this->email->message('
        <html>
        <head>

        <style>
          .card {
        border: 1px solid #ededed;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 43px 40px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #FFA100;
          }

          .page-footer{padding: 43px 40px;}

          body{background-color:#D9EBFF;}

          h2 {color: #002040; font-size: 16px;}

        </style>
        </head>
        <body>

         <div class="">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Nome:</h2>'.$nome.' <br>
          <h2>Email:</h2> '.$email.' <br>
              <h2>Tipo de Item:</h2> '.$item.' <br>
          <h2>Mensagem:</h2> '.$mensagem.' <br>
    </div>
     </div>


     <div class="page-footer">
        <p>Sua Empresa | Todos os direitos reservados</p>
        <p>Este formulário foi enviado direto do site suaempresa.com.br </p>
     </div>

        </body>
        </html>

    '); 

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');


    if ($this->email->send()){ 
        $this->checkEmail();
    }
    else{

        $this->load->view('errorEmail');      
    }
}
```

}

Comment: marque a resposta que resolveu usando o V verdinho do lado da pontuação correspondente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite!

Nessa linha vc tá passando um atributo num método que não espera nenhum atributo

```
$address = $this->enviaEmail($email);
```

Tente adicionar um ou mais atributos para processar os dados sem repetir os inputs, algo como:

```
public function enviaEmail($email){
```

Verifique também se ao chamar outro método no CodeIgniter ele consegue buscar os dados do POST, se não conseguir, envie-os como parâmetro para esta função.

E cuidado ao chamar a mesma função dentro de outra, pode gerar um loop de envios desnecessário!

Abraço

Answer (score 0):

Boa Noite!, valeu muito pela dica, funcionou aqui. 
Vou colocar as alterações que fiz aqui!

// na funcao checkEmail()

removi essa linha `$address = $this->enviaEmail($email);`

de

`public function checkEmail()`

alterei para

`public function checkEmail($email)`

de

```
$this->email->to($address);
```

alterei para

```
$this->email->to($email);
```

// na função enviaEmail(), fiz as seguintes alteraçoes

adicionei esse trecho `$emailTo = $this->checkEmail($email);`

e no IF, em vez de executar um método (que estava gerando os loops). Passei uma view, informando que o email foi enviado com sucesso!

```
if($this->email->send())
    {
        $this->load->view('formEnviado');          
    }
    else
    {
         $this->load->view('errorEmail');
    }
```